# Show that $f_n(x)=|x||x|^{1/n}$ is differentiable at $x\in [-1,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

While uniform convergence preserves continuity, it does not preserve differentiability. Find an explicit example of a sequence of differentiable function on $[-1,1]$ that converge uniformly to a function $f$ such that $f$ is not differentiable. Hint: Consider $|x|^{1+\frac 1n}$, show that these functions are differentiable, converge uniformly, and then show that the limit is not differentiable.

Following Hint, let $f_n(x)=|x|^{1+\frac 1n}$.

Let $c \in [-1,1].$ Then, $$\lim_{x \to c} \frac {|x||x|^{1/n}-|c||c|^{1/n}}{x-c}=?.$$

Show that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x).$ I claim that $f(x)=|x|.$ Note that $|x|^{1/n}\le 1 $ for all $x\in [-1,1]$. Then, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}||f_n-f||_u=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup(|x||x|^{1/n}-|x|)\le\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup(|x|-|x|)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup(0)=0.$$

And we know that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Could you tell me how to prove $f_n$ is differentiable at $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Can you first prove $f_n$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$?

Comment: By the definition of derivative, one can show that $f_n'(0)=0$ ( break the case $x\to0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$) And for $x\neq 0$,this is easy

Comment: @Eric Wofsey $\lim_{x \to c} \frac {xx^{1/n}-cc^{1/n}}{x-c}$. I don't know the next step.

Comment: @SihyunKim do you know the derivative of $xx^{\frac{1}{n}}
$? Then how about $(-x)(-x)^{\frac{1}{n}}$
for $x<0$?

Comment: @TonyMa To show that $xx^{\frac 1n}$ is differentiable, I have to compute $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{xx^{1/n}-cc^{1/n}}{x-c}.$ But, I don't know the next step. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: For the proof that $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$, use the inverse function rule for derivative(Do you know derivative of $x^n$?). After that, use product rule. For the proof of the theorems, please search in google. If you would like a study deep enough to answer you question, maybe you can use 'Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus' by Kenneth A.Ross